# how to get a sum total of each column and row - postgresql [Crosstab or Case]

Tags: postgresql, sum, pivot

I have to count the records according to the criterion, they are much more filters but I have summarized.

I could use either of two ways.

1#

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT dim_espacio.desc_estab, dim_tiempo.mes, count(*)::int
FROM hec_his INNER JOIN dim_espacio ON hec_his.id_espacio = dim_espacio.id_espacio 
INNER JOIN dim_tiempo ON hec_his.id_tiempo = dim_tiempo.id_tiempo 
WHERE (dim_tiempo.ano=''2012'' and hec_his.codigo1=''Z001'') 
GROUP  BY 1,2 ORDER  BY 1,2', 
$$VALUES ('01'), ('02')$$) AS ct (desc_estab character varying, "Enero" int, "Febrero" int)
```

2#

```
SELECT NULLIF(dim_espacio.desc_estab, 'TOTAL') AS Establecimiento,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '01' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Enero,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '02' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Febrero,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '03' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Marzo,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '04' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Abril,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '05' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Mayo,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '06' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Junio,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '07' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Julio,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '08' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Agosto,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '09' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Septiembre,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '10' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Octubre,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '11' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Noviembre,
COUNT(CASE mes WHEN '12' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS Diciembre,
COUNT(mes) AS Total 
FROM hec_his 
INNER JOIN dim_espacio ON hec_his.id_espacio = dim_espacio.id_espacio 
INNER JOIN dim_tiempo ON hec_his.id_tiempo = dim_tiempo.id_tiempo
WHERE (dim_tiempo.ano='2012' and hec_his.codigo1='Z001') 
GROUP BY desc_estab;
```

the result is the same but have trouble getting the totals rows and columns :
[image]

the result I want is something like this:
[image]

Comment: You can wrap your query as a `WITH` query, then `SELECT * UNION ALL SELECT sum(*)` from it (pseudocode alert).